# Dúvida sobre prototype

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Estou com uma dúvida básica em prototype no JavaScript, é o seguinte:

```
function MeuObjeto() {}

obj1 = new MeuObjeto
MeuObjeto.nome = "Lucas"

console.log(obj1.nome)
```

Resultado:

`Undefined`

Estou em dúvida em relação a porquê o prototype ao instanciar o MeuObjeto é 
MeuObjeto.prototype e não MeuObjeto?

Tipo se eu fizer:

```
obj1.__proto__ = MeuObjeto
```

O `console.log(obj1.nome)` vai resultar em "Lucas"
mas entendo que se eu fizesse `MeuObjeto.prototype.nome = "Lucas"` não daria `Undefined` igual anteriormente quando fizesse `obj1.nom`e porém eu não entendi a utilidade de por padrão ao instanciar uma função ser definido o prototype `__proto__` como `(nomeobjeto).prototype` em vez do `(nomeobjeto)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando uma função construtora é criada, o objeto `prototype` é criado simultaneamente.

E quando você faz:

```
MeuObjeto.nome = 'Lucas'
```

O que está acontecendo é que você está criando a propriedade 'nome' na **função** MeuObjeto e não no prototype dela e para que o cadeia de herança seja criada corretamente a gente precisa usar o new.

E fazendo:

```
obj1.nome
```

- Ele vai tentar procurar essa propriedade primeiro no `obj1`
- E depois no **protótipo** da `MeuObjeto`

Acho que esse post pode esclarecer melhor sua dúvida do motivo das propriedades ficarem no protótipo e não na função: https://www.instagram.com/p/B6yCC4dAhhC/

Comment: Boa noite, muito obrigado, tipo eu entendi isso de estar criando na função MeuObjeto e não no prototype dela mas só queria saber porquê foi projetado assim o JavaScript, tipo eu vi o instagram e gostei bastante me esclareceu muita coisa porém ainda achei meio forçado a explicação dela, afinal na quinta imagem usar Dog.prototype.bark para adicionar bark a Dog.prototype e todos poderem usar seria a mesma coisa se o __proto__ do Dog fosse Dog em vez de Dog.prototype daí simplesmente fazer Dog.bark poderia ser usado por todas as instâncias de Dog igual Dog.prototype.bark faz.

Comment: Eu imagino que o prototype tenha sido uma forma de "simplificar" a hierarquia. Quase como um "ponteiro" de um lista, para facilitar o caminho.

Comment: Entendi, me ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: Lembrando que isso é uma opinião minha. Não tenho nenhuma evidência de que seja essa a razão para o prototype.